# ¿Como mejorar estas consultas con entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq, signalr

estoy implementando una funcionalidad de chat relativamente sencilla, utilizo signalr y entity framework. Mi principal problema es evitar múltiples llamadas a la base de datos por eso quiero mejorar el código de obtener los chats.

Este es mi modelo:

```
public class Chat
{
    [Key]
    public int ChatID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime FechaCreacionChat { get; set; }
    public List<Mensaje> Mensaje { get; set; }
}
public class GroupChat: Chat
{
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Required]
    public string NombreGroupChat { get; set; }
    public List<UsersChat> UsersGroupChat { get; set; }
    public string ImagenGroupChat { get; set; }
}
public class PrivateChat: Chat
{
    public string Usuario1Id { get; set; }
    public string Usuario2Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Usuario1 { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Usuario2 { get; set; }
}
```

Uso herencia para identificar dos tipos de chats: grupales y privados.

```
public class Mensaje
{
    [Key]
    public int MensajeID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TextoMensaje { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaMensaje { get; set; }
    public string NombreArchivoMensaje { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ChatId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
}
public class UsersChat
{
    [Key]
    public int UsersChatID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ChatId { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Entonces en este método en ChatHub de signalr obtengo los chats privados y grupales en que se encuentra un usuario:

```
public async Task GetChats()//no debo obtener todos los chats
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
                using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    List<ChatView> listChats = new List<ChatView>();
                    var usuario = await db.Users.SingleAsync(x => x.UserName == name);
                    var chatsPrivate = await db.Chat.OfType<PrivateChat>()
                        .Include(x => x.Usuario1)
                        .Include(x => x.Usuario2)
                        .Where(x => x.Usuario1Id == usuario.Id || x.Usuario2Id == usuario.Id)
                        .ToListAsync();
                    var chatsGroup = await db.UsersChat.Include(x => x.Chat)
                        .Where(x => x.UsuarioId == usuario.Id)
                        .Select(x => x.Chat)
                        .OfType<GroupChat>()
                        .ToListAsync();
                    var gListChats = chatsGroup.Select(chat => new ChatView
                    {
                        ID = chat.ChatID,
                        FechaCreacion = chat.FechaCreacionChat,
                        Nombre = chat.NombreGroupChat,
                        Conectado = false,
                        Mensaje = db.Mensaje.Where(m => m.ChatId == chat.ChatID).Any()?
                                db.Mensaje.Where(m => m.ChatId == chat.ChatID)
                                .OrderByDescending(m => m.FechaMensaje)
                                .Select(x => new MensajeView
                                {
                                    FechaMensaje = x.FechaMensaje,
                                    MensajeID = x.MensajeID,
                                    NombreArchivoMensaje = x.NombreArchivoMensaje,
                                    TextoMensaje = x.TextoMensaje,
                                    Usuario = new UserView
                                    {
                                        Email = x.Usuario.Email,
                                        UserName = x.Usuario.UserName,
                                        PhoneNumber = x.Usuario.PhoneNumber
                                    }
                                })
                                .First()
                                :
                                null,
                        Imagen = "ImageChat?chatId="+chat.ChatID+ "&nameImage=" + chat.ImagenGroupChat
                    });
                    var pListChats =  chatsPrivate.Select(chat => new ChatView
                    {
                        ID = chat.ChatID,
                        FechaCreacion = chat.FechaCreacionChat,
                        Nombre = chat.Usuario1Id == usuario.Id ?
                                chat.Usuario2.UserName
                                :
                                chat.Usuario1.UserName,
                        Mensaje = db.Mensaje.Where(m => m.ChatId == chat.ChatID).Any()?
                                db.Mensaje.Where(m => m.ChatId == chat.ChatID)
                                .OrderByDescending(m => m.FechaMensaje)
                                .Select(x => new MensajeView
                                {
                                    FechaMensaje = x.FechaMensaje,
                                    MensajeID = x.MensajeID,
                                    NombreArchivoMensaje = x.NombreArchivoMensaje,
                                    TextoMensaje = x.TextoMensaje,
                                    Usuario = new UserView
                                    {
                                        Email = x.Usuario.Email,
                                        UserName = x.Usuario.UserName,
                                        PhoneNumber = x.Usuario.PhoneNumber
                                    }
                                })
                                .First()
                                :
                                null,
                        Conectado = chat.Usuario1Id == usuario.Id ?
                                db.Conexion.Any(x => x.UsuarioId == chat.Usuario2Id && x.ConectadoConexion == true)
                                :
                                db.Conexion.Any(x => x.UsuarioId == chat.Usuario1Id && x.ConectadoConexion == true),
                        Imagen = chat.Usuario1Id == usuario.Id ?
                            "ImagenPerfil?nameImage=" + chat.Usuario2.ImagenPerfil + "&name=" + chat.Usuario2.UserName
                            :
                            "ImagenPerfil?nameImage=" + chat.Usuario1.ImagenPerfil + "&name=" + chat.Usuario1.UserName
                    });
                    listChats.AddRange(gListChats);
                    listChats.AddRange(pListChats);
                    listChats.OrderByDescending(x => x.Mensaje.FechaMensaje);
                     await Clients.Caller.setChats(listChats);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await Clients.Caller.showErrorMessage($"Se ha Producido un error en ChatHub => GetChats : \n{e.Message}\n{e.InnerException}");
        }
    }
```

El esta funcionando pero sospecho que hago mas llamadas de las necesarias por ejemplo aveces tengo que hacer un `Any()` para saber si existe y si es asi hacer la consulta de lo contrario pongo null para evitar una excepción cuando llamo a  `First()` o `Single()`.
Ejemplo:

```
Mensaje = db.Mensaje.Where(m => m.ChatId == chat.ChatID).Any()?
                                db.Mensaje.Where(m => m.ChatId == chat.ChatID)
                                .OrderByDescending(m => m.FechaMensaje)
                                .Select(x => new MensajeView
                                {
                                    FechaMensaje = x.FechaMensaje,
                                    MensajeID = x.MensajeID,
                                    NombreArchivoMensaje = x.NombreArchivoMensaje,
                                    TextoMensaje = x.TextoMensaje,
                                    Usuario = new UserView
                                    {
                                        Email = x.Usuario.Email,
                                        UserName = x.Usuario.UserName,
                                        PhoneNumber = x.Usuario.PhoneNumber
                                    }
                                })
                                .First()
                                :
                                null
```

Y este gran fragmento se ejecutara por cada chat ya que el cliente espera todos los chats con el ultimo mensaje de dicho chat.

Esto es lo que muestro al cliente:

[image: Diseño web]

Comment: Para evitar la excepción al usar `First` puedes usar `FirstOrDefault` si no recuerdo mal.

Comment: Buen aporte, eso elimina las dos llamadas de `Any()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En vez de comprobar con `Any()` si existe un registro, puedes utilizar `FirstOrDefault()` ya que este retorna `null` si no existe ningun registro que seria lo mismo que retornar `null` si `Any()` retornar `false`

En otra palabras, este codigo:

```
var resultado = list.Any() ? lista.Where(x=>x.Id == 4).First() : null;
```

Es *un tanto*<sub>(ve la nota)</sub> equivalente a:

```
var resultado = lista.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == 4);
```

Tu codigo para verificar si existe un mensaje seria:

```
Mensaje = db.Mensaje.Where(m => m.ChatId == chat.ChatID)
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.FechaMensaje)
                    .Select(x => new MensajeView {
                        FechaMensaje = x.FechaMensaje,
                        MensajeID = x.MensajeID,
                        NombreArchivoMensaje = x.NombreArchivoMensaje,
                        TextoMensaje = x.TextoMensaje,
                        Usuario = new UserView {
                            Email = x.Usuario.Email,
                            UserName = x.Usuario.UserName,
                            PhoneNumber = x.Usuario.PhoneNumber
                        }
                    })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Esto no lanzara ningun error en caso de que no exista ningun registro porque el metodo `FirstOrDefault()` sera el que ejecute el sql generado de la expresion y si no retorna nada, entonces `null` sera retornado. Asi entonces te ahorras la consulta del `.Any()` haciendo tu consulta mas eficiente.

Ahora bien, no en todos los casos esto te es aplicable ya que si utilizas un `OrderBy()` en la consulta, no vas a obtener el resultado que esperas:

```
db.Mensajes.Where(x=>x.Id == chatid).FirstOrDefault();
```

No te retornara lo mismo que:

```
db.Mensajes.Where(x=>x.Id == chatid).OrderByDescending(m => m.FechaMensaje).FirstOrDefault();
```

Ya que la primera obtendra el primer registro sin ordenar ascendentemente.

---

Nota 1: digo un tanto porque esto:

```
val existe = lista.Where(x=>x.Id).Any();
```

No es hace lo mismo que:

```
val existe = lista.Any(x=>x.Id);
```

Debido a que la primera tiene que **primero filtrar la coleccion** y luego comprobar si existe un registro en la coleccion ya filtrada, recorriendo la collecion 2 veces. Mientras que la segunda, se **deja de recorrer la colleccion desde que se encuentra un registro** por lo  recorre la colleccion 1 sola vez.

---

Nota 2: Me gustaria tambien aclarar que:

```
 db.Mensajes.Where(x=>x.Id == chatid).FirstOrDefault();
```

Es equivalente a:

```
db.Mensajes.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == chatid);
```

Pero solo cuando utilizas Entity Framework, ya que `FirstOrDefault()` es el metodo que ejecuta el sql de la expresion asi tambien como los metodos `ToList()`, `First()` y `Any()`. Si lo utilizas en una coleccion en memoria, la nota 1 muestra la diferencia.

Comment: Excelente, las notas en especial son un agregado que me han ayudado mucho. Este era el tipo de respuesta que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

Prodrias reorganizar las tablas normalizando agrego los campos basicos:

```
User
--------
UserId int
UserName varchar(100)

GrupoChat
------
GrupoChatId int
UsuarioId int
ChatId     int

Chat
------
ChatId    int
NombreChat varchar
Aplication varchar
IsPrivate   bit
IsActive   bit     //si todos los usuarios se desconectaron o el chat se cerro se pone a 0

Message  //asi se pueden obtener los mensajes por chat y por usuario
----
MessageId  int
ChatId    int 
UserId    int
Message   varchar
```

Para la llamada inicial desde la vista cargas :
GetAllChats(int usuarioId)
despues cargas cada chat activo del usuario.
GetAllMessages(int GroupChatId)

y signalr Actualiza solo los mensajes nuevos, filtrados por grupo usuario
UpdateNewMessage(int GroupChatId)

Comment: Gracias, pero no veo que esto solucione el problema planteado eliminar los viajes de ida y vuelta ala base de datos, ademas un chat grupal debe tener una lista de usuario.

Comment: Al inicio de cada session de usuario se carga el todos los chats hacen una consulta general, despues por cada mensaje de cada usuario lo envias directamente al grupo en particular, Clients.Group(GroupName,Exceptional).receiveMessage(msgFrom, msg);    y guardas ese mensaje en base de datos.